# Starting activity on clicking on widget layout

Tags: android, widget

I have widget and i am showing some data on it and i want to open some Activity on clicking on widget i tried all the things from google but its not working.I hope i will get some help from here.I am a newbie in widget Please Help 
Thanks in advance

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static RemoteViews views;

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    CharSequence widgetText = NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context);
    CharSequence notetext = NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.loadNotePref(context);
    views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.wd_note, notetext);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);



}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);

        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, configPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);


    }

}




@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {

}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static RemoteViews views;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (configIntent.getAction().equals("your_unique_string")) {
            /* your logic goes here whatever you want to do onclick of widget view */
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);


            Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
            configIntent.setAction("your_unique_string");

            PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, configPendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);


        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {

    }
}
```

Comment: @faizmir, I have I deleted whole updateAppWidget() block because was not needed. I am still doing, I am not done. Wait a minute man.

Comment: It should solve your problem @faizmir, please check now.

Comment: Ok, @faizmir, send your whole project file in infofuniversities@gmail.com. I will solve it. Let's delete these all comments.